# Junit Test Case Builder (JUB) plug-in in Eclipse for Junit testcases automation

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin

I am using JUB (JUnit TestCase Builder) plugin in Eclipse. I have downloaded JUB plugin and installed according to the instructions given in the following website,

http://jub.sourceforge.net/

While selecting the option "Build Junit Test Case", am getting information like "The chosen operation is not currently available".

Anyone facing the same problem? Kindly reply.

If there is anyother plugin for Junit Test cases Automation will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about JUB plugin for eclipse, but I would suggest you codePRO analytix for Eclipse for automating test cases since it is easy to install and use.

You can find the details of codePRO analytix [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codepro-analytix)

CodePRO Analytix as a direct plugin is available in Eclipse Market place only for Eclipse versions 3.6 or below. However it can be installed and used with Eclipse versions 3.7 or more by following the below steps. But be aware of the problems which may occur due to version conflicts.

Installing CodePRO in Eclipse:

1. Download CodePRO v7.1.0 from [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/eclipse_toolreleases/products/codepro/integration/v7.1.0_201109091219/3.6/CodeProAnalytix_v7.1.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.6.zip)
2. In Eclipse choose Help --> Install New Software...
3. In the Install window which appears click on the Add button. In Add Repository dialog box which appears, click Archive... button. Locate the downloaded zip file and click Open. The details of the plugin installed will be displayed below. Click select All and Click on the Next button. Accept the terms and conditions and proceed with the installation.
4. Once installation is complete restart eclipse for the changes to affect.

Once installation is completed you can generate JUnit test cases by

1. Right click the required file
2. choose codePRO Tools -> Generate test cases.

Your test cases will be generated as a separated project.